# Internet connection speed higher after midnight

Tags: wireless-networking, router, connection, lag

In the last few weeks I've begun noticing that my internet connection speeds up noticeably after midnight. In fact, it is only past midnight that I am able to download at high speeds (700-800 KB/s which looks like the maximum for my connection) via torrents or similar. In the morning or afternoon, if I'm lucky, I am only able to reach 100 KB/s (not necessarily downloading via torrent).

I have a download speed of about 7.20 Mbps and an upload speed of 0.30 Mbps, so I shouldn't have too many problems. Should I?

Also, connecting to Minecraft multiplayer servers before midnight I get huge lag (my "lag value" is registered as 30000+), while past midnight I get absolutely no lag (40-70 max); after midnight there are also more people on these servers, so it makes no sense.

I went into the router settings to see if there was some kind of connection block, or pre-set schedule, but I couldn't find anything of interest. I have a NETGEAR DGN2200v3 router.

Is there some reason as to why this happens? Can it be resolved?

Comment: Who is your provider?

Comment: First step would be to reset the router to factory settings then upgrade the firmware.  If the problem still happens then contact your ISP about the problem.

Comment: @jmq Vodafone Omnitel (Italy).

Comment: @Ramhound I've already done all that. :( I think I'm going to have to contact my ISP, then...

Answer (score -1):

You've probably got some ISP traffic shaping going on... this will slow your connection down during peak times

Comment: From what the OP is experiencing, traffic shaping is a possible reason for their Internet performance fluctuating at the times given. Could the downvote be explained please?